# Selective group by, np.where Pandas/Python query

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

df_have

```
A  B C
1  1  10
1  1  10
1  2  5
1  3  6
1  4  7
```

df_want

```
A  B C    D
1  1  10  20
1  1  10  20
1  2  5   5
1  3  6   6
1  4  7   7
```

Trying to group by column A, B only if column B is 1 or 2. If B is 1 or 2 then output column D as the SUM of column C. Else keep set column D = column C.

Sample code gives error:

```
df_want['D']=np.where((df_want['B'].isin([1,2]), 
             df_want['A','B'].map(df_want.groupby(['A','B'])['C'].sum()), 
             df_want['C'])
```

The issue is occuring here: df_want['A','B'].map.. if I only put df_want.A.map then the code runs but the output is wrong. I need it to only map the sum if col B is 1 or 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `sum` to `transform('sum')`

```
np.where(df_want['B'].isin([1,2]), 
             df_want.groupby(['A','B'])['C'].transform('sum'), df_want['C'])
```

Comment: can you please have a look into my question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62083576/pandas-row-filters-and-and-division-from-specific-rows-and-columns]

Answer (score 2):

You can use loc

```
df['D'] = df['C'].copy()
df.loc[df['B'].isin([1,2]), 'D'] = df.loc[df['B'].isin([1,2])].groupby(['A', 'B']).C.transform('sum')


    A   B   C   D
0   1   1   10  20
1   1   1   10  20
2   1   2   5   5
3   1   3   6   6
4   1   4   7   7
```